# Continuity in countable subspaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider a countable space $X$ as a subspace of some compact euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n<\infty$.

We can undow the countable space $X$ with discrete topology.

I know that every function from a space with discrete topology is continuous.

Is it still the case for some countable space? From my point of view, as we are in finite dimension, we have equivalence of norms and therefore the continuity follows anyway for countable spaces.

Thank you

Comment: You seem a bit confused. Yes, any function from a discrete space is continuous, whether or not the space is countable. But, a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ already has a topology and if it is infinite then it may not be discrete and, as has already been demonstrated, there may be functions from it which are not continuous.

Comment: Does it means we should use subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of discrete topology for such countable subspace ? I am always considering discrete space so I don't really understand your second point

Comment: It's your question, you can give a countable *set* $X$ whatever topology you wish. But once you define it as a *subspace* of $\mathbb R^n$ then the topology is fixed. It may or may not be discrete. You need to decide what possible sets $X$ you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the counter example above states it, it is false, be careful, all topologies are not metrizable and all metrics are not equivalent to norms, which means you don't have the "topology equivalence" you are mentioning in finite dimension, only two norms define the same topology.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example: $X=\{0,1,\frac  1 2,\frac  13,...\}, f(\frac 1 n )=1, f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply